# Chaining Selectors to Get certain Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-selectors

Creating a bunch of rows each with a checkbox used for mass deletes but my jquery selector statement is wrong. I want to get only the checkboxes of class "js-delete-checkbox"

Below, is the code, albeit chopped down for the sake of brevity, since I am pretty sure the problem is in my selector syntax

```
//The View
 @foreach (NewClubEmail e in Model.DraftEmails)
 {

    <input type="checkbox" value="@e.Id" name="delete" class="js-delete-checkbox"/><br />

  }


//The AJAX code that gets the checkboxes
<script type="text/javascript">

[...]
var checkedValues = $('.js-delete-checkbox input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {

                            return this.value;

                    }).get();
[...]
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us the actual generated HTML from View/Source in the browser so we can more accurately understand what the target is.

Answer (score 0):

Need to flip the order:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked.js-delete-checkbox')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your actual HTML and what you need to distinguish it from, but it looks to me like you want just this:

```
$('.js-delete-checkbox:checked')
```

Note: when all the attributes are on the same object, you don't want any spaces in the selector because spaces force the selector engine to look for parent/descendant rather than looking for all attributes on the same object.

I don't see any reason that you need `input:checkbox` as part of the selector because presumably `.js-delete-checkbox` already eliminates things that aren't checkboxes.

Comment: There is a "Select all" checkbox so that's why I need to be more selective, I guess.

Comment: @Slinky - show us your actual HTML and we can help much better.  You're basically asking us to guess what will work.  This selector won't change whether a select all checkbox is or is not included in the selection.